# How to use fetch in query() in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

How to fetch column directly in query()?

Something like:

```
$userID = _openConnection()->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = "' . admin
. '"', PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Instead of

```
$userID = _openConnection()->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = "' . admin 
. '"')->fetchColumn();
```

The problem is that if the statement doesn't return anything, calling fetchColumn() would throw a fatal error, and I think that if I do it inside the Query(), I would get false.

Thanks!

PS: The first statement var_dump

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(42) "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = "admin"" }
```

Comment: What does `_openConnection()` function do? Opens a new connection for the every query to run?

Comment: Returns PDO object connection (DSN,user,pass)

Comment: Why not validate the query returned results then use `->fetchColumn` if there was a result?

Comment: @FDL I think you're right, I will try your approach, just thought that there was a more direct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of PDO is quite wrong.

- you need to create only single connection and use it all the way
- you have to use prepared statements
- there is no point in chaining methods - it makes your code looks ugly. Write vertically, not horizontally. If you want to shorten your code - create a *function*:

  ```
  function fetchCol()
  {
      global $pdo;
      $params = func_get_args();
      $query = array_shift($params);
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute($params);
      return $stmt->fetchColumn();
  }
  ```

used this way

```
$pdo = _openConnection(); // do it only ONCE per application

$userID = fetchCol('SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = ?',admin);
```

this approach will make your core *really* short yet meaningful and readable.

Comment: Where does `$args` come from?

Comment: Do you mean, do it only ONCE per class?